# Excel UDF returns True but not False?

Tags: vba, excel

I was trying to save a combination of worksheet functions as a UDF because i tend to forget exactly how it goes. I use this combination to compare lists:

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH([value], [range], [match_type])),False,True)
```

But in my attempt to right a simple two line macro a ran into a bit of a problem. It seems that the VBA code  i wrote to mimic the worksheet combo will will return true just fine but not false. Instead for a value not within the given range it returns the #value! error. It is my understanding that this is operation to data type mismatch but i don't see why.

As a side note the IF in the above worksheet combo is used to reverse the output from the ISNA function. Its a bit confusing if your search returns false for a positive result.

Thanks for you help if you have something better let me know. Here is my code.

```
Public Function CompareLists(variable As Variant, list As Range, match_type As String)  As Boolean

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(variable,     list, match_type)) = False Then

    CompareLists = True

    Else
        CompareLists = False  
    End If

End Function
```

**** For those of you asking for inputs it could be anything. I usually use this to compare id numbers for hundreds of things. They sometime contain letters and  numbers.

An example would be trying to find the number 3 in the list 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 where 3 is on one sheet and the list is on another.

Comment: What's an example of the data input, like variable=????, list example, match_type example?

Comment: By example we mean a test case or walkthrough that provides example input, sample parameters you use for the function, as well as expected & actual output for those inputs.

Answer (score 2):

Try this version:

```
Public Function CompareLists(variable As Variant, list As Range, match_type As Long) As Boolean
    CompareLists = WorksheetFunction.IsNA(Application.Match(variable, list, match_type))
End Function
```

The name "CompareLists" seems confusing to me. A more accurate name would be:

```
Public Function NotInList(variable As Variant, list As Range, match_type As Long) As Boolean
  NotInList = WorksheetFunction.IsNA(Application.Match(variable, list, match_type))
End Function
```

This makes it more readable inline:

```
If NotInList(3, Range("A1:A8"), 0) Then
' rest of code
```

Comment: Well should have just thought about it instead of using stupid worksheet functions.  This is the exact situation for loops are well....uh for.  Just used a for loop with an if statement inside. See what happens when you try to use your chemistry degree to program :P

Comment: If this solved the issue, click the arrow at the upper left of the answer to 'accept it'. :)

Comment: My function worked for me, but if you'd rather loop, be my guest!

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using a loop (as seen in your comments) then I highly suggest you dump the range to a variant array first.

Here is a sample function with a loop. Note that I called it IsMissing since it just feels more natural when the user is asserting something IS the case, not IS NOT the case (personal perference).

```
Function IsMissing(ByVal search_value As Variant, _
                   ByVal search_range As range) As Boolean

Dim varray As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim found As Boolean

varray = search_range.value

For i = 1 To UBound(varray, 1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(varray, 2)
        If Len(varray(i, j)) <> 0 Then
            If varray(i, j) = search_value Then
                found = True
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next

IsMissing = found

End Function
```

P.S. This can still be optimized, but I wanted to keep it simple. I did add a check for cell length so you don't waste time with blank cells, though.

Comment: +1 for the function name, but in your last If statement, wouldn't "IsMissing = Not found" be the same thing?

Comment: What I meant was, at the end of your function the value of **IsMissing** is always the opposite of **found**. So instead of an If-Else-End If statement, you could just put "IsMissing = Not found"

Comment: You're totally right. I must have left than in from the first ver. of the code when I wrote it down - thank you for catching it :)